# PrimeNG table filtering and sorting on each column doesn't work

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm creating a table using PrimeNG.
I want to allow the user to sort AND filter by column.
I can successfully sort, but when I try to type in the filter text input of any column, the input loses focus and the column gets sorted.
I've debugged a little and it seems like the sorting functionality of primeNG is activated whenever a click is captured in the header of the table. Since my filter input is inside the header, when I try to click on it to start typing, it activates the sort and I lose focus.

Stackblitz reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-g9uxkf

Any idea on how I could counter this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you enable the stackblitz to fork please.

Comment: can you update your question with some code and  enable the stackblitz

Comment: How do I enable the stackblitz? I changed the link, maybe now you can fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was capturing the click event on the text input (the filter) and stopping its propagation.

```
clickOnFilter(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the input tag helped me to resolve the issue.. Now Search is also working and sorting is also working

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

or

```
<input pInputText type="text" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (input)="dt1.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)" [value]="dt1.filters[col.field]?.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked

```
<p-columnFilter (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
```

considering you are using `"<p-sortIcon>name of the column </p-sortIcon> <p-columnFilter (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>` then it worked for me